# Como rodar um video dentro de uma GUI

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, youtube, gui

boa noite, estou com um problema. Preciso rodar um video do youtube dentro de uma interface GUI (com Python).

Um usuário da comunidade me ajudou fornecendo o seguinte código:

https://gist.github.com/rodgomesc/2c6d85f85ac0cc28a3d5

porém, ele foi escrito usando PyQt4. Mas todo meu projeto final é feito na versão 3 do python.

Alguém saberia me dizer como fazer o mesmo utilizando PyQt5 ou se consigo instalar o PyQt4 na versão 3 do python (já tentei muito).

Obs.: ideias com outros módulos também são muito bem vindas.

Comment: Cara, a classe QWebView, que é a mais importante nesse caso, também existe no PyQt5. Tenta atualizar os imports.

Answer (score 1):

Então, a única coisa que vem na minha cabeça é utilizar um widget que renderize html propriamente, exatamente como está proposto no código que você postou.

Fazendo algumas modificações, consegui ter um resultado bastante semelhante no GNU/Linux:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()

html = '<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zqFPTkxu-Rc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>'
url = QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/")  
web.setHtml(html, url)

web.show()
app.exec()
```

A diferença é que na versão 5, não há mais a classe QString, podendo-se utilizar strings Python padrão no lugar.

Além disso, em vez de usar o widget `QWebView`, utilizei o `QWebEngineView` que, de acordo com a [documentação](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets), substitui o QWebKit em prol de um suporte mais atual a HTML, CSS e Javascript. No entanto, de acordo com a mesma fonte, é possível que você tenha problemas em utilizar esse widget no windows.

Caso esse seja o seu caso, talvez seja melhor trocar de biblioteca. O **wxPython** tem suporte a html, só não sei como está o suporte deles para Python 3. Além dela, você pode dar uma olhada no **GTK+**, que também tem um webkit que pode resolver o seu problema.